# Optimizer about require.js

Tags: optimization, requirejs, amd

I use `require.js` to organize my app module file

in the build phase I want to optimizer the js file

but because the module is in separate file, what I can do is only minify the js fies?

can I concat some file together for reduce http request?Or it make the `AMD` no sense?

Answer (score 0):

Optimizer can concatenate all your modules into a single file. I recently blogged about this: [**understangin AMD & RequireJS**](http://www.devbridge.com/articles/understanding-amd-requirejs).